# Show that the language is regular

Tags: computability, automata, regular-language

Let $$B_n=\{a^k \ \mid \ k \text{ is a multiple of } n\}$$

Show that for each $n \geq 1$, the language $B_n$ is regular.

$$$$

Could you give me some hints how we coukd show this??

Do we have to construct a NFA that accepts this language??

Comment: To show that a language is regular, you can either construct a DFA or NFA that recognises it, or construct a regular expression that describes it.

Comment: It is probably easiest to describe a DFA that accepts B_n.  If you try for a few small cases of n the pattern should be clear.

Comment: In addition to the other suggestions, you could construct a regular grammar that generates $B_n$. But a DFA is easy. HINT: You’ll want $n$ states.

Comment: To construct a DFA we do the following: When we are at the state $q_i$ and we "see" a $"a"$ we go to the state $q_{i+1}$. The state $q_n$ is the final state and we have that $(q_n, a) \mapsto q_1$. Is this correct??

Comment: @travisj I don't quite agree with you. For this specific problem, finding a regular expression is easier and in any case, much shorter.

Comment: @MaryStar, I think so (I'm new to automata, so I'm not certain I understand the notation).  I would just create a cycle with n states (0, ..., n-1) and think of each state as the residue class mod n.  You start at state zero and each time you see an "a" you increment to the next state.  State n-1 wraps to state 0.  Then your final/accept states are just the 0-state (same as start).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- If $a^n$ was a single letter, say $\alpha$, then $B_n$ could be represented by regular expression $\alpha^*$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$